# Objective c- Show Loading Screen before main thread gets blocked completely

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

In my app I have two methods to hide and show a subview of a view controller called

```
 -(void)hideCurrentView
 -(void)showCurrentView
```

They are always called together. When calling hideCurrentView I want to start showing a loading screen and then hide this loading screen when showCurrentView has shown all necessary ui elements. My loading screen is a view with an activity indicator as a subview. The problem is that I have to do all the actions that happen in hideCurrentView and showCurrentView on the main thread. That is why my loading screen will never show up. :-(

I tried to put the show loading screen method to a background thread:

```
-(void)hideCurrentView {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, (unsigned long)NULL), ^(void) {
        [self showLoadingScreen];
    });
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(hideCurrentViewOnMainThread) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}

-(void)showCurrentView {
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showCurrentViewOnMainThread) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

That does not work. The loading screen never shows up because the main thread is blocked. I also tried showing the loading screen directly on the main thread but it doesn´t work too.

Can anyone tell me hoew to show the loading screen before doing the ui actions and then hide it again when all ui actions have finished?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: yes. never ever block the main thread. if you: you're doing it wrong

Comment: iOS doesn't like it either btw

Comment: Why do you think you must do your blocking thingy on the main thread?

Comment: What i thought is that the performSelectorOnMainThread blocks the main thread until everything has finished. What I do in hideCurrentView and showCurrentView is just adding and removing subviews and doing some view animations. And in my oppinion I should really do these things on the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call `showLoadingScreen` in a background thread if you are just adding a subview. (or more generally manipulating the UI)
I'm guessing you have something in your `hideCurrentViewOnMainThread` that is not UI related and blocks the main thread and it's that part of the code that should be run in another thread.